What is the rank of a superoperator of the form $\Xi (\cdot) = \sum_i^n U_i^\dagger {\cdot}\, U_i$?
Given a superoperator $\Xi$ as
$\Xi (\cdot) = \sum_i^n U_i^\dagger \cdot U_i $
where $U_i$ are unitary. What can I say about the image of this map or about the rank of $\Xi$?
Also, do you have some literature where I can find basic linear algebra but with superoperators? Thank you.

most of the theory about quantum maps and channels is essentially "linear algebra about superoperators". You seem to be asking about the rank (as linear operators) of mixed-unitary channels (or "mixed-unitary maps", given with your definitions they wouldn't be trace-preserving). A good reference on this is Watrous' book.
